# Multi-Field Searching that show results as you type

Tags: ms-access, search, vba

I had gotten my question answered by a colleague of mine, but I wanted to re-post here in case anyone else has the issue, and to pose the question, which you'll note at the end. The original post, if interested, is here: [Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810301/access-multi-field-search-with-results-as-you-type/46810398?noredirect=1#comment80595371_46810398)

Many thanks to all in the community here, particularly @Andre for your help!

It was strange, but when I did that, it kept trying to put in all my letters backwards. Example: If I searched "Smith", it would enter it as "htims". I'm sure it had something to do with the on click event, but I had a friend look at it and I think she cracked it! It looks like this (I've added a comment to what the new line(s) of code is/are):

First, the textbox click event whereby when you click the box, it clears the text and resets the search (no need for a reset button)

```
Private Sub txtSearch_Click()
    Me.txtSearch.SetFocus 'new line of code
    Me.txtSearch.Text = ""
    Me.Requery
With Me.txtSearch
    .SetFocus
    .SelStart
End With
End Sub
```

This is the actual search, that will search multiple fields

```
Private Sub txtSearch_Change()
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim sSearch As String
    On Error Resume Next

If Me.txtSearch.Text <> "" Then
    sSearch = "'*" & Replace(Me.txtSearch.Text, "'", "''") & "*'"
    strFilter = "[Last_Name] Like " & sSearch & " OR [First_Name] Like " & sSearch & " OR [SSN] Like " & sSearch
    Me.Filter = strFilter
    Me.FilterOn = True
Else
    Me.Filter = ""
    Me.FilterOn = False
End If

If Me.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then 'new line of code
    Me.Filter = "" 'new line of code
    Me.FilterOn = False 'new line of code
    Me.txtSearch.SetFocus 'new line of code
    Me.txtSearch.Text = "" 'new line of code
Exit Sub 'new line of code
End If 'new line of code

With Me.txtSearch
    .SetFocus
    .SelStart = Len(Me.txtSearch.Text)
End With
End Sub
```

This seems to be working great. And while I'm considering this issue complete, I do have a question, if you could help me identify, why were the letters going in backwards when I replaced the .Text with a .Value?

Thank you all very much for your help!

Comment: If the answer provided by @Andre in the original post  solved your problem, please consider accepting it to help other users who may face the same problem.

Comment: My mistake, I thought I clicked that when I put it up. Done on the original post. Also thank you @KostasK. for your help with the backwards text. I figured it had something to do with that, but I guess I misinterpreted what the .SelStart does, that it refocuses each time. I will implement in my DB and see if I can understand it a bit more. Thank you!

Comment: .SelStart (selection start) simply positions the cursor to the value given. If no value given, it positions at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to change the `Click` event to `Enter` and scrap the `.SetFocus` since the control will have the focus:

```
Private Sub txtSearch_Enter()
    With Me
        .txtSearch.Value = ""
        .Requery
    End With
End Sub
```

Regarding the difference between `.Text` and `.Value`:

The `.Text` property updates with every keystroke you make where the `.Value` property gets updated **only** when the control loses focus.

On the `Change` event, you should check two things: a) the textbox has a value (.Text) to apply the filter and b) the recordcount to clear the filter if no records returned.

```
Private Sub txtSearch_Change()
    Dim strFilter As String, sSearch As String

    On Error Resume Next
    With me
        If .txtSearch.Text <> "" Then
            sSearch = "'*" & Replace(.txtSearch.Text, "'", "''") & "*'"
            strFilter = "[Last_Name] Like " & sSearch & " OR [First_Name] Like " & sSearch & " OR [SSN] Like " & sSearch
           .Filter = strFilter
           .FilterOn = True
        End If

        If .Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then
           .Filter = "" 
           .FilterOn = False 
        End If 
    End With
End Sub
```

The reason for the backward letters, was the `.SelStart` property where the cursor was jumping at the beginning every time you typed a letter, thus giving you the impression it was flipping the word backwards.