# How to show query results in an Access form?

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

[image]

The form contains a textbox, a button and a subform (which I created by just dragging the query into the form). The table contains 8 fields. When any of those field keywords are typed in, all records matching those keywords should display in the same form. But instead of that, Access shows the results in a separate window. How can I fix this?

I haven't included the complete where clause to this, here's my query:

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Account_Name Like "*" & [Forms]![Form1]![Text0] & "*" OR Opportunity_Name Like "*" & [Forms]![Form1]![Text0] & "*" OR .....

And I have assigned this query to the button. Here's my on click event of the button:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command2_Click

    Dim stDocName As String

    stDocName = "Search2"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.Requery
    subform.Requery

Exit_Command2_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command2_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command2_Click
End Sub
```

It does the work but the only problem is that it shows data in a separate window. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It opens a separate window because that is what the code is written to do. Remove both DoCmd lines. Then code to requery must reference subform container control.

`Me.subformContainerName.Requery`

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question. Instead of clicking on search button, how can I modify the textbox keypress event to filter and display the results when the user keeps typing?

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810301/access-multi-field-search-with-results-as-you-type